Is it possible to activate German SIM abroad for non-EU person?
There are many German mobile operators selling SIM cards online. It is possible to order them with post forwarding abroad. However, it seems that activation of all these cards is possible only in Germany. At least, for online activation German or EU passport is requested. Is it possible to activate German SIM abroad for non-EU person?

Germany is very strict with SIM card activation, maybe the strictest in EU. How about getting a SIM card from another EU country to use in Germany? Roaming is free within the European Union.

Point is, I have German phone number for 12 years. My provider instantly terminated my contract despite positive balance and full compliance without giving a reason. Therefore, I m seeking another German provider to transfer my number.

In 2019 I bought and activated an alditalk SIM with a foreign passport.
In 2022 I did the same with a prepaid o2 sim card.
In 2023 I did it with 2x Telekom, congstar, vodafone callya. No issues once again.
There was a video identification in both cases, and notably it was in German. There were no issues with my passport being a foreign one. No questions were asked about my location or residence. I did activate them whilst in Germany but for some of them I had a foreign IP address and that did not cause issues, so that should be fine. That's indifferent from someone roaming in Germany. Worst case you can try to use a VPN.
Depending on where you're located also keep in mind that video identification services might not be available outside reasonable hours for a Germany resident to be attempting this on, so trying it at 4AM German time might lead to hours of waiting before you get a person checking your documents.
You may need to put a German address for invoicing reasons, but in my case it was not validated, I just put my hotel address in.
A bigger issue is that some operators only allow top-ups with SEPA direct debit or thru use of top-up codes you can get in German supermarkets. Do check what operators allow top-ups with cards before you do this. You might also be able to use services like Wise to get a SEPA account you can do direct debits on.
Many German prepaid lines also by default have running monthly costs and are not PAYG, look for options that are "ohne grundgebühr". All 3 big operators have options, but these may not be directly available from them or available from wherever you're buying your sims from. Vodafone and o2 IIRC wanted to ship these sims directly to me after I filled out a form on their website.
So yeah, to answer your core question, it is doable, but more generally it is probably more pain than it is worth.

Thank you so much for so detailed reply. I was astonished today when refused with activation when calling for ID verification from an EU country and showing a passport, which grants me visa free entry to Germany, but being still refused. VPN is an option to try.

@BorisZinchenko what issues did you face? (Also passport having visa free entry is irrelevant, I am a visa national and had no issues, no operator checked if I'm legally in Germany (I am))

Vodafone required EU residence permit. O2 rejected without giving a reason. Lebara on chat told that activation is not possible outside of Germany. Aldi I ordered delivery but feel that it will be lost money. Most interestingly, Fonic where I was a loyal client for 12 years instantly blocked my SIM asserting "excessive usage abroad" (in the EU). This SIM has been used for banking SMS only. I feel something changes there for stricter regulations.

@BorisZinchenko interesting, Vodafone did not require to see my residence permit. Do give them all a try again I'd say, I have at times dealt with tired/angry/annoyed verification people that hung up on me for not parsing everything they're saying, but retrying worked.

Vodafone uses Deutsche Post ID app. On a call I was showing a paper given by Immigration Authority of an EU country granting me legal residence. It has been refused with a requirement to show a card, not a paper. It looks crazy itself because I might be just a tourist! Maybe I will make another try tomorrow. Thank you again for all the help and suggestions.

@BorisZinchenko postident will only take passports and residence permit cards, try your passport instead?

Update. Tried today Post ID twice with other officers. Foreign non-EU passport rejected. EU residence permit on paper rejected. EU driving license rejected.

I ordered 5 cards from different providers to German address of post forwarding service. I suppose that it will take 2 to 3 weeks for them to arrive abroad. Then I will try activation through VPN in their apps. But I suspect that they all will revert to standard Post ID. If I will have time, I will update this thread on my results then.
